# python GUI button manipulates label text

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter, label

Hej,

I want to program a GUI in Python that compares a prompted word (from a list) with an entry. This shall be possible several times, so that I want to make a button that erases both the entry and the label and then prompts the next word from the list.
Thus, clicking the button shall manipulate the text displayed on the label.
Bus how do I do this?

My code excerpt is:

```
from Tkinter import *
i = 0  
vocablist = ['one', 'two', 'three']
np.random.shuffle(vocablist)
vocab = vocablist[i]
(...)

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    (...)

        self.label = Tkinter.Label(self, text=vocab,anchor="w") 
        self.label.grid(column=1,row=0)

    def clear_text():
        global i                
        self.entry.delete(0, 'end')
        i += 1 # don't know if this works!
        self.label.insert(0, vocab) # this does not work!

    button_next = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"next", command=clear_text)
    button_next.grid(column=1,row=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('rehearse vocabulary: translate!')
    app.mainloop()
```

I also tried

```
self.label.config(text=vocab)
```

instead of the .insert-function.

I am wondering if the problem is the command or if it does not work to update the counter and then automatically update the variable "vocab" to the next element from the list?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `self.label.config(text=vocab)` is the correct solution. You say you tried it, but didn't say what happened when you did.

Comment: It's possible that the whole thing doesn't work because the import statement is `from Tkinter import *` but then it's accessed with `Tkinter.Widgetname`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I found a solution using self.label.config(text=vocablist[i]) instead of vocab. By this, the counter works.

Comment: You assigned `vocab = vocablist[i]`, so I don't see why `text=vocab` wouldn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `widget['attribute'] = 'value'`. Do the following:

```
def action(event=None): # event in case you bind to a keypress
    entry.delete('0', END) # clear the entry
    label['text'] = "" # set label's widget text to ""
    next_word()
```

where `entry` is your entry widget, `label` is your label and `next_word()` prompts for the next word.